# apply order by after combining results from two tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables with same columns. am using oracle 10g.

```
TableA
------
id  status
---------------

1   W
2   R

TableB
------
id  status
---------------

1   W
3   S
```

I have two tables. i get results from both the tables using UNION as below.

```
select id, status 
from TableA 
union 
select id, status 
from TableB 
order by status;
```

if i do that, is order by applied for both the queries?

My requirement is first it has to combine the results then it has to apply `order by`...

How can i do that?

Thanks!

Comment: you first query seems fine. the `order by` takes effect after bother queries has been combined.

Comment: As JW said, your first query is fine.  According to [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries004.htm#SQLRF52343), "You cannot specify the order_by_clause in the subquery of these operators", which implies that the `order by` is applied to the whole set.

Answer (score 2):

Given the data you've shown, your query will return this:

```
ID   STATUS
--   ------
 2   R
 3   S
 1   W
```

That's because UNION will return only unique rows and the (1, 'W') row has a duplicate.

If you want to include all rows, even duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`:

```
select id, status 
from TableA 
union all
select id, status 
from TableB 
order by status;
```

With `UNION ALL` your query will return this:

```
ID   STATUS
--   ------
 2   R
 3   S
 1   W
 1   W
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
select id, status 
from (select id, status from TableA 
      union select id, status from TableB) 
order by status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, status 
from TableA 
union 
select id, status 
from TableB 
order by 2; -- status
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need Distinct :

```
Select Distinct id, status 
from (
      select id, status from TableA 
      union
      select id, status from TableB)
order by status
```

Comment: the `UNION` limits results to distinct values by default. To get duplicate rows you have to ask for them by using `UNION ALL`.